# Can you get latest Beta build automatically though package.json and npm

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, package.json

We have a project that has a dependency that always needs to be the latest beta build from an npm library. Unfortunately, there are -dev builds in there as well.

For example, there could be the following versions in the "x-library".

```
"1.2.3-dev.294   // published today
"1.2.3-beta.123" // <--- the one we want published yesterday
"1.2.3-dev.293"  // published a week ago
"1.2.3-beta.122" // published a month ago
```

Is it possible to get the latest 'beta' build automatically in a package.json like so:

```
devDependencies: {
  ...
  "x-library": "latest-beta"  // just for clarity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this functionality is available through npm.  There's not even the possibility of using regex to define your dependency version currently.

You could cobble together a solution yourself.  Make a bash script `update-and-install.sh` using these pieces:

- get JSON with all available versions
  `npm show my-package versions --json`
- filter the JSON to get `beta` versions only
- use the package [semver-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver-parser) and its method [compareSemVer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver-parser#comparesemverversion-base-strict) to sort for the latest of those betas
- use `sed` to edit your package.json to set the dependency to the desired version
- run `npm install`

Don't know if that's helpful, but that's what I would try if this were a project requirement.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.